# Welcome to Nginx In Danginx

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, nginx

I have a VPS with CentOS and DirectAdmin installed.
This VPS only have one site with WordPress CMS but Apache have very usage of 1 GB Ram.
for this i buy license and install Danginx plugin.after installing dangnix, my site and IP only show "Welcome to Nginx" text and every other files show 404 error page.
after many Google searchs, everyone says install new ioncube loader but i installed this before Dangnix installation and more than 2 time reinstall.
php -v command also show ioncube loader has installed but my site still show Welcome text.
when i restart apache with service httpd restart command show this error :

NameVirtualHost 79.127.127.143:8888 has no VirtualHosts
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs

after many edits now this command show only "NameVirtualHost 79.127.127.143:8888 has no VirtualHosts" error.

Sorry for my bad english.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that it is port 8888. If you go to your website, default port is 80. Nginx only shows the message "Welcome to Nginx" if the port is not getting anywhere, so this is a configuration problem in Nginx.